# reverse transition in javafx inside SequentialTransition

Tags: java, javafx, reverse

Given a transition t that I want to play in reverse, I use the code

```
t.jumpTo(t.getTotalDuration());
t.setRate(-1);
```

this means that I jump to the end of the transition and play in backwards. 
My problem is that if I play this transition as part of a sequential or parallel transition, then it changes the rate to its absolute value, so it then plays it forward. Is there any way to "truly" reverse the transition, namely to get a new transition but with rate=1, so it would still be in reverse inside sequential and parallel transitions?

Answer (score 2):

For transition this is simple: Just use a `Interpolator` that returns the value at `1-fraction`:

```
public class ReverseInterpolator extends Interpolator {

    private final Interpolator reverse;

    public ReverseInterpolator(Interpolator reverse) {
        if (reverse == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    @Override
    protected double curve(double t) {
        return reverse.interpolate(0d, 1d, 1 - t);
    }


    public static Interpolator reverse(Interpolator interpolator) {
        return (interpolator instanceof ReverseInterpolator)
                ? ((ReverseInterpolator) interpolator).reverse
                : new ReverseInterpolator(interpolator);
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    rect1.setFill(Color.RED);

    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 200, 100, 100);
    rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    Pane root = new Pane(rect1, rect2);

    TranslateTransition transition1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), rect1);
    transition1.setFromX(0);
    transition1.setToX(400);

    TranslateTransition transition2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), rect2);
    transition2.setFromX(0);
    transition2.setToX(400);

    ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(transition1, transition2);
    transition.setOnFinished(evt -> {
        transition2.setInterpolator(ReverseInterpolator.reverse(transition2.getInterpolator()));
        transition.play();
    });
    transition.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

For general `Animation`s this is a bit more tricky. You could write a `Transition` that sets the time of the animation on every frame:

```
public class AnimationTransition extends Transition {
    private final Animation animation;

    public AnimationTransition(Animation animation) {
        this.animation = animation;
        setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        setCycleDuration(animation.getCycleDuration());
        setCycleCount(animation.getCycleCount());
        statusProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            switch(newValue) {
                case PAUSED:
                    animation.pause();
                    break;
                case STOPPED:
                    animation.stop();
            }
        });

        // don't actually procede except for playfrom calls
        animation.setRate(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        animation.playFrom(animation.getCycleDuration().multiply(frac));
    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    rect1.setFill(Color.RED);

    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 200, 100, 100);
    rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    Pane root = new Pane(rect1, rect2);

    TranslateTransition transition1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), rect1);
    transition1.setFromX(0);
    transition1.setToX(400);


    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rect2.translateXProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(rect2.translateXProperty(), 400d))
    );
    AnimationTransition transition2 = new AnimationTransition(timeline);

    ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(transition1, transition2);
    transition.setOnFinished(evt -> {
        transition2.setInterpolator(ReverseInterpolator.reverse(transition2.getInterpolator()));
        transition.play();
    });
    transition.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: There is still something weird with the first code (for the transition) when I use transition1.setByX(200) instead of setting a beginning and an end. If I just reverse the first transition and then run transition1.play(), it works ok, but if I run new ParallelTransition(transition1).play(), then it still go in reverse but starts in a different location.